# Select substrings on an entire DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I am working with a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
    Date              Close
1   2020.01.02 00:00  1.12142
2   2020.01.02 01:00  1.12187
3   2020.01.02 02:00  1.12182    
4   2020.01.02 03:00  1.12209    
5   2020.01.02 04:00  1.12221
```

In this DataFrame the Date contains the Date AND the hour.

But I want to create another DataFrame with different columns for date and hour that looks like this:

```
    Date        Hour   Close
1   2020.01.02  00:00  1.12142    
2   2020.01.02  01:00  1.12187    
3   2020.01.02  02:00  1.12182    
4   2020.01.02  03:00  1.12209    
5   2020.01.02  04:00  1.12221
```

Could somebody tell me how to do it "easily" please?

Comment: Why don't you use `datetime` and `timedelta` type instead of strings?

Comment: Because this is a data file I didnt create myself, but just downloaded it and I need to format that column. I know how to do it using lists but I am trying to do it "directly" with another DataFrame so I dont loose time. Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Let us try `to_datetime`

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y.%m.%d %H:%M')
df['Date'] = s.dt.date
df['Hour'] = s.dt.strftime('%H:%M')
df
Out[20]: 
         Date    Close   Hour
1  2020-01-02  1.12142  00:00
2  2020-01-02  1.12187  01:00
3  2020-01-02  1.12182  02:00
```

Comment: I couldnt implement this solution. I dont know how to make it work. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
df.rename(columns={'Date':'DateOld'}, inplace=True)
df['Date'] = df['DateOld'].apply(lambda row: row.split(' ')[0])
df['Hour'] = df['DateOld'].apply(lambda row: row.split(' ')[-1])
```

But I can recommend using `datetime` objects instad of strings, as noted in the comments.

Comment: When I do it I get KeyError: 'DateOld'

Comment: I have solved this little error by simply using a new DataFrame to store the "new" 3 columns, so thanks a lot.